# use a class in another DLL in C#

Tags: c#, class, dll, parameters

I have a project in which i created a class called "validator".

i also created a DLL that has a function that i want to pass the validator class as a parameter. but the DLL doesn't know the class in my project cause it is a different DLL.

i also can't add a reference in the dll to the project because the project has already a reference to the DLL (can't make circular references).

how do i get the DLL to recognize the validator class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need 1) a redesign or 2) a refactoring effort that creates a third class library that can be used by both of your current DLLs.

Comment: a third DLL that both the Project and the DLL use, sounds Good :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Define an interface in the DLL, that has the needed functions (like bool Validate()).

Have the validator class implement the interface and give it to the DLL.

Comment: What do you mean in "Give it to the DLL" ? i think the problem with that solution is that if i change the interface in my project , i will have to cahnge it in the dll....

Comment: Give an instance of the validator class to the method in the DLL that expects the validator feature.

Answer (score 0):

does it have to be a parameter? Can't u just create a non-static method?
If you really want to , sounds like you have to create another project and build a different class.( that's if you want to reference the method using dll)